# API for manipulating SQL Server database schema

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am searching for a .NET API which allows to manipulate the database schema. For instance, the API should be able to create new tables or alter table structures without the need of using SQL like  `Create TABLE Example (column1 int)`. Is there an API which provides this functionality?

Best regards,
Thorsten

Answer (score 1):

You can explore SQL Server Management Objects[SMO], which is a programmatic way of interacting with SQL Server instance.

For example, you can add column to a table using column class. [Read more] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.column?view=sql-smo-160)

You can learn more about [SMO model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/smo-object-model?view=sql-server-ver15)